# How to create an IP for virtual server

Tags: ip, dedicated-server

I want to ask something maybe noobish.

When i purchase an Virtual server(VPS) they give me an IP for that server.

I want to know how they create the IP and set it for the virtual server. Do they buy it from the internet provider or ?

I know that they have server machine, but do i need something else also so i can create an IPs and set them for all virtual servers that i set up on my dedicated server ?

Thanks in advance and sorry for this silly question, if you can give me some more information about the whole procedure i'll be very thankful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends whether your ISP is a LIR or not. When they are they can get the IPs in ranges at their local RIR (RIPE, ARIN, etc.). They pay a yearly fee depending on the amount of IPs they have. If they are not a LIR, they probably use ranges owned by another LIR.

You cannot create your own IPs. You can however use internal ranges (not accessible from the Internet, eg. 192.168.0.0/16. 10.0.0.0/8, etc.).

Comment: Does it means that all VPS on that dedicated server will have one same IP for all of them ?

Comment: No, you can add as many as you want (as long you still have available ones).

Comment: I can add local IPs which will not be reachable from the internet i know that. But i can not create any IPs in range, for example 187.253.12.10, 187.253.12.11, 187.253.12.12, 187.253.12.13. How can i make that ?

Comment: Does your ISP allow you to use those IPs?

Comment: I have up to 5 ips in my net plan.

Comment: Well you can add those 5 IPs to the server, whats the problem there? You can obviously only allocate the exact IPs that you get from your ISP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24381/discussion-between-jeroen-and-tony-stark).